# Why is Brahman identified with Shunya(Void) in the Mahopanishad?

Tags: upanishads, brahman

In the Maha Upanishad we come across the following -

> शून्यं तत्प्रकृतिर्माया ब्रह्मविज्ञानमित्यपि । शिवः पुरुष ईशानो
> नित्यमात्मेति कथ्यते ॥ ६१॥
>
> VI-61. **That Brahman has been identified with emptiness(Shunya),**
> Prakriti, Maya and also consciousness. It has also been said to be
> "Shiva, pure Spirit, the Lord, the eternal and the self".

My question is How can Brahman be identified as Shunya? Wouldn't that also mean that ShunyavAda is valid as well?

Comment: Yes. The shunya (void) interpretation exists too. Shankara's interpretation of shunya is usually devoid of any ego (emptyness).

Comment: Śūnya doesn't necessarily mean the śūnyatā of Bauddha siddhāntas. It's even used in Trika.

Comment: @Bingming then what does it mean? Can you explain in an answer?

Comment: @Bingming There are multiple schools of philosophies. Even Buddhists don't have a single *sunya* - there are multiple of them. Trika and Natha tradition are known to have buddhist influence, so sunya from Trika is most like to come from Buddhism. Please note guru Rinpoche came around a millennia before trika system, so I believe in the reverse influence.